Accessing values from grid::unit objects in R
Are there any functions to access the values in a unit object from grid package in R.
I am trying to access the locations of certain points from a complex grob to add text labels to them.
For example, I am able to get the x axis locations as positionx.
positionx <- structure(list(list(1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL, 0L), list(2.4, NULL, 7L)), 
                                             class = c("unit", "unit_v2")), 201L),
                           list( 1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL, 0L), list(1.5, NULL, 7L)), 
                                              class = c("unit",  "unit_v2")), 201L), 
                           list(1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL,  0L),  list(-4, NULL, 7L)), 
                                             class = c("unit", "unit_v2")),  201L),
                           list(1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL, 0L), list(-14, NULL, 7L)), 
                                             class = c("unit", "unit_v2")), 201L),
                           list(1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL, 0L), list(-3, NULL, 7L)), 
                                             class = c("unit", "unit_v2")), 201L), 
                           list(1, structure(list(list(0.5, NULL,  0L), list(1.65, NULL, 7L)), 
                                             class = c("unit", "unit_v2")), 201L)), 
                      class = c("unit", "unit_v2"))

# [1] sum(0.5npc, 2.4mm)  sum(0.5npc, 1.5mm)  sum(0.5npc, -4mm)   sum(0.5npc, -14mm)  sum(0.5npc, -3mm)  
# [6] sum(0.5npc, 1.65mm)



I want ro identify points to the left and right of 0.5npc to place text labels accordingly.
I know I can use unclass and unlist to fetch the required values. Are there any existing functions to do the same ?

There are a number of different functions in the grid package for converting and extracting values from unit objects. In your case, you can subtract 0.5npc from positionx and use grid::convertX to extract the difference in mm.
convertX(positionx - unit(0.5, 'npc'), 'mm', TRUE)
#> [1]   2.40   1.50  -4.00 -14.00  -3.00   1.65

Change the last argument to FALSE if you want these numbers to remain as unit objects in mm.
